# What django do when allow_migrate() on a database router returns false?

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-database

I'm writing a `DB router` to control what should be or not applied on the DB, so, implemented allow_migrate().

Here is what I did:

```
def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
      if app_label == 'django_q':
         return db == 'tasks'
      elif app_label != 'django_q': 
         return db == 'default'
```

I was expecting that when a `router` returns `False`, then an app wouldn't be applied on the current DB at all, it happened somehow, no tables were created, but, the entire app migration list is added to `django_migrations` table at the DB.

I was expecting that when `allow_migrate()` return `False`, then Django won't add anything to current DB about this app, but if this behavior is the expected, then, this is the same as `migrate --fake`, right? if this so, I prefer doing it manually for the other DB.

I have done some research to see what is actually done when `allow_migrate()` returns `False` but got no luck.

Thanks in advance.